# Failing to get values from tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been trying to get the values of the tags in my form but am unable to. This is the jquery http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/.

**Index.php**

```
<form>
    <p> Normally this input field will be hidden &mdash; we leave it visible here so you can see how it is manipulated by the widget:
        <input name="tags" id="mySingleField" value="Apple, Orange" disabled="true">
    </p>
    <ul id="singleFieldTags"></ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php echo $_POST["tags"]; ?>
```

**Javascript**

```
 $(function(){
 var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];

//-------------------------------
// Minimal
//-------------------------------
$('#myTags').tagit();

//-------------------------------
// Single field
//-------------------------------
$('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
    availableTags: sampleTags,
    // This will make Tag-it submit a single form value, as a comma-delimited field.
    singleField: true,
    singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField')
});

// singleFieldTags2 is an INPUT element, rather than a UL as in the other 
// examples, so it automatically defaults to singleField.
$('#singleFieldTags2').tagit({
    availableTags: sampleTags
});

//-------------------------------
// Preloading data in markup
//-------------------------------
$('#myULTags').tagit({
    availableTags: sampleTags, // this param is of course optional. it's for autocomplete.
    // configure the name of the input field (will be submitted with form), default: item[tags]
    itemName: 'item',
    fieldName: 'tags'
});

//-------------------------------
// Tag events
//-------------------------------
var eventTags = $('#eventTags');

var addEvent = function(text) {
    $('#events_container').append(text + '<br>');
};

eventTags.tagit({
    availableTags: sampleTags,
    beforeTagAdded: function(evt, ui) {
        if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
            addEvent('beforeTagAdded: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
        }
    },
    afterTagAdded: function(evt, ui) {
        if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
            addEvent('afterTagAdded: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
        }
    },
    beforeTagRemoved: function(evt, ui) {
        addEvent('beforeTagRemoved: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
    },
    afterTagRemoved: function(evt, ui) {
        addEvent('afterTagRemoved: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
    },
    onTagClicked: function(evt, ui) {
        addEvent('onTagClicked: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
    },
    onTagExists: function(evt, ui) {
        addEvent('onTagExists: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.existingTag));
    }
});

//-------------------------------
// Read-only
//-------------------------------
$('#readOnlyTags').tagit({
    readOnly: true
});

//-------------------------------
// Tag-it methods
//-------------------------------
$('#methodTags').tagit({
    availableTags: sampleTags
});

//-------------------------------
// Allow spaces without quotes.
//-------------------------------
$('#allowSpacesTags').tagit({
    availableTags: sampleTags,
    allowSpaces: true
});

//-------------------------------
// Remove confirmation
//-------------------------------
$('#removeConfirmationTags').tagit({
    availableTags: sampleTags,
    removeConfirmation: true
});

 });
```

Comment: And the problem/question is? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that `disabled="true"` from the `input` form element & check once again.

Use following piece code in place of yours & check.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p> Normally this input field will be hidden &mdash; we leave it visible here so you can see how it is manipulated by the widget:
        <input name="tags" id="mySingleField" value="Apple, Orange">
    </p>
    <ul id="singleFieldTags"></ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php echo $_POST["tags"]; ?>
```

**OK, here is my full code. Check this.**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="tagit/js/tag-it.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="tagit/css/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
     var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];

    //-------------------------------
    // Minimal
    //-------------------------------
    $('#myTags').tagit();

    //-------------------------------
    // Single field
    //-------------------------------
    $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
        availableTags: sampleTags,
        // This will make Tag-it submit a single form value, as a comma-delimited field.
        singleField: true,
        singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField')
    });

    // singleFieldTags2 is an INPUT element, rather than a UL as in the other
    // examples, so it automatically defaults to singleField.
    $('#singleFieldTags2').tagit({
        availableTags: sampleTags
    });

    //-------------------------------
    // Preloading data in markup
    //-------------------------------
    $('#myULTags').tagit({
        availableTags: sampleTags, // this param is of course optional. it's for autocomplete.
        // configure the name of the input field (will be submitted with form), default: item[tags]
        itemName: 'item',
        fieldName: 'tags'
    });

    //-------------------------------
    // Tag events
    //-------------------------------
    var eventTags = $('#eventTags');

    var addEvent = function(text) {
        $('#events_container').append(text + '<br>');
    };

    eventTags.tagit({
        availableTags: sampleTags,
        beforeTagAdded: function(evt, ui) {
            if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
                addEvent('beforeTagAdded: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
            }
        },
        afterTagAdded: function(evt, ui) {
            if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
                addEvent('afterTagAdded: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
            }
        },
        beforeTagRemoved: function(evt, ui) {
            addEvent('beforeTagRemoved: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
        },
        afterTagRemoved: function(evt, ui) {
            addEvent('afterTagRemoved: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
        },
        onTagClicked: function(evt, ui) {
            addEvent('onTagClicked: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
        },
        onTagExists: function(evt, ui) {
            addEvent('onTagExists: ' + eventTags.tagit('tagLabel', ui.existingTag));
        }
    });

    //-------------------------------
    // Read-only
    //-------------------------------
    $('#readOnlyTags').tagit({
        readOnly: true
    });

    //-------------------------------
    // Tag-it methods
    //-------------------------------
    $('#methodTags').tagit({
        availableTags: sampleTags
    });

    //-------------------------------
    // Allow spaces without quotes.
    //-------------------------------
    $('#allowSpacesTags').tagit({
        availableTags: sampleTags,
        allowSpaces: true
    });

    //-------------------------------
    // Remove confirmation
    //-------------------------------
    $('#removeConfirmationTags').tagit({
        availableTags: sampleTags,
        removeConfirmation: true
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <p> Normally this input field will be hidden &mdash; we leave it visible here so you can see how it is manipulated by the widget:
            <input name="tags" id="mySingleField" value="Apple, Orange">
        </p>
        <ul id="singleFieldTags"></ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php echo $_POST["tags"]; ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my case when replaced ```<input name="tags" id="mySingleField" value="Apple, Orange" disabled="false">``` with ealier one & click on submit button I can able to see those Tags in my POST request.

Comment: I copied the same code and replaced the older one with it and yet I see no result.

Comment: But, I can able to see the ```POST``` content after clicking on Submit button on this line ```<?php echo $_POST["tags"]; ?>```

Comment: @DakshB I've updated my full source code. Check that. Reassign the require Javascript & css file accordingly.